# .htaccess redirect to subfolder, not working perfectly

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have written a simple redirect condition as:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^my-domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://my-domain.com/hu/$1 [L,R=301]
```

It redirects correctly from `www.mysite.com` to `mysite.com/hu/`

But it does not redirect `mysite.com` to `mysite.com/hu/`

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've cleary copied this code without understanding it. This is a typical htaccess to remove the `www.` part of a domain.

To redirect your homepage to a subfolder, use this code instead :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?my-domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^hu/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://my-domain.com/hu/$1 [L,R=301]
```